# Conditional IE Statments - if modern browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My JavaScript need only to target modern browsers (IE9, FF, Chrome ect.) and excluding IE8 and older. I have been experimenting but I am not sure if it works (don't have proper IE testing facilities).

I was thinking about adding a script for newer than IE8 and then again for all non IE:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8)]><script src="sites/all/themes/customtheme/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->


<!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="sites/all/themes/customtheme/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script><!--<![endif]-->
```

Anybody have any experience or code snippet for adding to script to modern browsers and exclude IE8 and older?

Comment: FF2 classifies as a modern browser? You should feature detect rather than browser detect.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one tag:

```
<![if gt IE 8]>
<script src="sites/all/themes/customtheme/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<![endif]>
```

IE will use the condition and only include the script for IE9 and later, and other browsers will ignore the conditional tags, and as they doesn't form a comment tag they will include the script.

See [downlevel-revealed conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed).

Comment: Perfect. So that work for all modern browsers. Then I can just add a specific for IE8 or older? Like:

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="sites/all/themes/customtheme/js/customIE.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to your question,

what you should be aiming to do is feature detect what a browser is capable of.

Modernizr can help with much of this:

http://modernizr.com/

I say this because have basically put all browsers except old IE into a bucket of so called "modern browsers", when really will you script run on FF2, or Opera, or my TV?

Comment: I am doing some (apparently) difficult JS that doesn't work in older browsers. And I prefer to just disable it for older browser instead of starting to hack my way through.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use conditional Css's as you have done ....there are many variations on how to invoke and target each and every IE version.

Also this css trick might help

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Hope it helps.